# ngRepeat through entries in map and filter entries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ngRepeat on a Map that gives me a "(key, value)" pair for each iteration.  I now need to write a filter on this to limit some of the results I get back.  I defined my filter to have two parameters.  I pass one parameter in the ngRepeat call, so I should expect to get two parameters. The parameter I manually pass is a boolean.  In the debugger both of those parameters were set, and the second parameter was "true", which is what I was passing, so I would expect the first parameter to correspond to my "(key, value)" pair.  What I got for the first parameter was an essentially empty Object.

The reference in my HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, thing) in thingMap | limitThings:showOnlyFailed">
```

The "thingMap" is a map keyed by a "name" property, whose values are "thing" objects.

Here's my filter definition, representing what I expected to see in that first parameter:

```
thingModule.filter("limitThings", ['ThingsService', function(ThingsService) {
return function(entry, showOnlyFailed) {
    return !showOnlyFailed || ThingsService.anyFailuresInList(entry.thing);
};
}]);
```

When I get into the debugger, the value of "entry" is just "Object {}".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what just-boris is saying is correct, but I modified his example to make it a little clearer.  When you use ng-repeat with an object, then the whole object is passed into the filter, not each entry.

I did some filtering with angular.forEach based on a 'failed' property in the value of the object.

http://plnkr.co/edit/B2WOiSm2vZiQBKS1wlmJ?p=preview

```
app.filter('limitThings', function() {
  return function(entry, showOnlyFailed) {
    console.log("Entry: " + entry + " Only Failed: " + showOnlyFailed);
    var filteredMap = {};
    angular.forEach(entry, function(value, key)
    {
      if(!showOnlyFailed || !value.failed)
      {
        filteredMap[key] = value;
      }
    });
    return filteredMap;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You see `thingMap` as argument named `entry`. If you got an empty object, then you thing map is empty.

I've created a small plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/miipnB?p=preview where you can see that hash map of your things are passed corectly.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I should have been clearer.  Before I added this filter, this iteration through the map was working fine.  The map is NOT empty.  I'm referencing both key and value in the markup, and it's working fine.  I'm only having trouble with this filter.

Comment: Then not enough information to answer. I have an example when I see an expected behaviour. Try to update used angular version to latest. I am using `1.2.12`

Comment: Oh, is the parameter sent to the filter the MAP or the ENTRY?  I would have guessed the entry, but your example seems to imply it's the map itself.

Comment: Really, you see entrie map. Angular filters was designed to convert some value to another that it not always is a filtering.

Comment: Native angular filter named `filter` (a bit confusing) intended to filter arrays only. You have to write own filter that returns filtered map